# Mac Like Keyboard for Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard-layout, mac

I work with lot of Devanagari text - my Macbook started showing blue screen of death because of GPU issues, its a good machine and I did not want to spend another 2k so decided to wipe OSX Clean and run Ubuntu on it. So far - I like it.

However the most important thing I miss is the keyboard. I wanted to get https://ubcsanskrit.ca/keyboards.html similar keyboard.

I went through http://blog.karawoo.com/2014/11/12/reconfigure-keyboard-layout-ubuntu/ and followed all the steps sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data bit it did not work for me.

```
Specially I am interested in these 5 combination 
Base layout - Devanagari Unicode 
Shift - more unicode
Option - some more unicode
shift+Option - SOme more unicode
Capslock - Normal english (US)
Shift + capslock - Capital English (US)
```

Can experts here please suggest me how can I create Mac equivalent keyboard in Ubuntu. Thanks a million in advance.

Comment: Let me stop you here.  Apple has a repair program for Macbooks with this issue.  If you can get it to an Apple Authorized repairman, they should fix it at absolutely no charge.  If you can't get it to a Apple Authorized repair center, then you can mail it in to apple.  Here is the link to the Program for more information: https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/

Comment: @Daniel - Thanks for sharing this info however here are few things. 1. Its purchased used in craigslist in 2011 2) I upgraded the RAM, SSD and Battery myself so in apple terms I voided the warranty. 3) GPU issues were so bad that I had to reballed the GPU chip with high temp solder. It worked great for another 1.5 year. Also Apple ended the free replacement program. So now all 2011 owners are on their own. I run OSX El Capitan in Virutal Environment and it works great but has high CPU taxing